# What is the return value for visual block mode in vimscript?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to display the current mode of vim on the status line by mapping the return value of mode function by using a dictionary:

```
let g:modeMap={
    \ 'n'      : 'Normal',
    \ 'i'      : 'Insert',
    \ 'R'      : 'Replace',
              ...
    \ 'v'      : 'Visual',
    \ 'V'      : 'Visual Line',
    \ '\<C-V>' : 'Visual Block'
    \}

set laststatus=2
set statusline=%{g:modeMap[mode()]}
```

It works well for almost all modes, however it throws the following error message in case of switching to visual block mode:

```
E716: Key not present in Dictionary: ^V
```

I've also tried the string `<\C-V>` found [here](https://gabri.me/blog/diy-vim-statusline), `CTRL-V` found [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#mode%28%29) and `^V` which was written out in the error message but neither of them was correct.

Tested with versions:

- Vim 7.4, Ubuntu 16.04
- Vim 8.1, Debian 9

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`'\<C-V>'` -- is a literal string in VimL.

You must use double quotes to make the substitution work: `"\<C-V>"`.