# Is it possible to express Control-V for comparison without typing the literal control character into source code?

Tags: vim

Consider the following toy function. Note that the expression `^V` is generated by typing `Control-V, Control-V` in vim; when I copied the character here it did not display, which is why I am using two characters to represent it.

```
function! WasLastVisualModeBlock()
    if visualmode() == "^V"
      echom "Found Visual Block"
    endif
endfunction
```

Is there some equivalent function I could write that does not require me to have the control character in my source code?

I'm envisioning something like the following.

```
function! WasLastVisualModeBlock()
    if visualmode() == magic_function_to_expand_my_exprssion("\<C-v>")
      echom "Found Visual Block"
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Duplicate of [What is the return value for visual block mode in vimscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56274737/what-is-the-return-value-for-visual-block-mode-in-vimscript) In short, "\<C-V>" is already "magic" enough.

Comment: @Matt, It's the same answer but I'm not sure it's the same question. Thank you for the pointer though!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the return value for visual block mode in vimscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56274737/what-is-the-return-value-for-visual-block-mode-in-vimscript)